# Loop over list of files to merge according their names

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Files in the directory look like that:

```
A_1_email.txt
A_1_phone.txt
A_2_email.txt
A_2_phone.txt
B_1_email.txt
B_1_phone.txt
B_2_email.txt
B_2_phone.txt
```

What I want:
To merge files `A_1_email.txt` and `A_1_phone.txt`; to merge files  `B_1_email.txt` and `B_1_phone.txt` and so on.
What I mean by that: if first to flags of files names matches (for example A to A; 1 to 1) than merge files.

How I tried to do this:

```
ls * | cut -d "_" -f 1-2  | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}' > names && for name in   
$(cat names); do
```

And I am lost here, really don't know how should I go on further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the files all have tab-separated name-value pairs, where the value is email or phone as appropriate. If that's not the case, do some pre-sorting or otherwise modify as appropriate.

```
ls *_{email,phone}.txt |
  cut -d "_" -f1-2 | # could also do this with variable expansion
    sort -u | 
      awk '{ printf("join %s_email.txt %s_phone.txt\n", $1, $1) }' |
        sh
```

What this does is to identify the unique prefixes for the files and use 'awk' to generate shell commands for joining the pairs, which are then piped into `sh` to actually run the commands.

Comment: @dogbane When dealing with general file names, I agree. But this entire question depends explicitly on names having a specific form. If you'd care to identify where it can go wrong *given that constraint on the file names*, I'll make the needed changes.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber you can give a superficially correct answer on SO and forget that you're leaving an example that many future readers will misunderstand and modify. At the very least I hope some of them will read the Wooledge article dogbane linked.

Comment: @kojiro If you feel the answer is only superficially correct, by all means submit an answer that you feel to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The following are based on @MichaelJ.Barber's answer (which had the excellent idea of using `join`), but with the specific intention to avoid the [dangerous practice of parsing the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
# Simple loop: avoids subshells, pipelines
for file in *_email.txt; do
    if [[ -r "$file" && -r "${file%_*}_phone.txt" ]]; then
        join "$file" "${file%_*}_phone.txt"
    fi
done
```

or

```
##
# Use IFS and a function to avoid contaminating the global environment.
joinEmailPhone() {
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local -x LC_COLLATE=C # Ensure glob expansion sorting makes sense.
    # According to `man (1) bash`, globs expand sorted "alphabetically".
    # If we use LC_COLLATE=C, we don't need to sort again.
    # Use an awk test (!seen[$0]++) to ensure uniqueness and a parameter expansion instead of cut
    awk '!seen[$0]++{ printf("join %s_email.txt %s_phone.txt\n", $1, $1) }' <<< "${*%_*}" | sh
}
joinEmailPhone *
```

But in all probability (again assuming `LC_COLLATE=C`) you can get away with:

```
printf 'join %s %s\n' * | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `printf '%s\n' *_{email,phone}.txt | ...` instead of `ls *-...` in the given scenario, i. e. no newline chars in file path names are to be expected. At least one external command less!

Comment: This seems not to actually address the question. Is it intended as a comment on my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the email files, using the `read` command
with the proper value of `IFS` to split the file name into the necessary parts.
Note that this does use one non-POSIX feature that `bash` provides, namely
using a here-string (`<<<`) to pass the value of `$email` to the `read` command.

```
for email in *_email.txt; do
    IFS=_ read fst snd <<< $email
    phone=${fst}_${snd}_phone.txt
    # merge $email and $phone
done
```